# Give user access to folder without changing ownership?

Tags: files, permissions

I have a script that works with `/etc/NetworkManager`:

```
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root    4096 Apr  3  2017 NetworkManager/
```

I want to give the user `programX` write permission for this folder without changing the ownership.

Is that possible or would I have to change the ownership?

Comment: `chmod o+w /etc/NetworkManager` should be enough, but will defeat all security since this folder will be writable to all users. Adding this user to group `root` is not a good option too. What your script do? Maybe there is a way to make your script work in a more integrated way, that adding `programX` to group `netdev` or `network` could be a viable solution

Comment: @nwildner it edits `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is what access control lists are for.

```
setfacl -m 'u:programX:rwx' /etc/NetworkManager
```

The user account `programX` now has read, write, and traverse access to the directory, but does not have ownership access.

Bonus way of doing this on FreeBSD with its NFS ACLs:

```
setfacl -m 'u:programX:rwxD::allow' /etc/NetworkManager
```

## Further reading

- [Operation not supported with setfacl?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402415/)

Comment: You should add that the `x` in the permissions is required on directories to be able to open them/list files in them. I did `rw` on a pure data directory, and got a little surprise with it !

Answer (score 3):

You can use ACLs for this, first of make sure that the acl package is installed.

After that you can run

```
setfacl -m u:programX:rw NetworkManager/
```