# Operation not supported with setfacl?

Tags: permissions, acl

*This is a follow up question to this [Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402384/give-user-access-to-folder-without-changing-ownership).*

I tried the command on my laptop it worked:

```
setfacl -m 'u:programX:rwx' /etc/NetworkManager
```

I checked that my embedded device had `acl` installed and marked correct.

But I'm finding when using the command on the embedded device I get `setfacl: /etc/NetworkManager: Operation not supported`.

When I check `man setfacl` my version of `acl` seems to support the `-m` flag.

Why wouldn't `acl` on the device support the operation, when it works fine on my laptop?

---

Result of `mount | grep -w /`:

```
/dev/block/mtd/by-name/linuxroot on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered)
```

Comment: What's the output of `mount | grep -w /` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick added to question

Comment: What is the output of `tune2fs -l /dev/sdaX | grep "Default mount options"` replace `sdaX` with your device.

Comment: @GAD3R it returns `tune2fs: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sdaX Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock`

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride GAD3R specifically mentioned to replace sdaX with your device, hence try `tune2fs -l /dev/block/mtd/by-name/linuxroot | grep "Default mount"`

Comment: This article could help someone with more information https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/setfacl-operation-not-supported-in-linux/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The ext4 code in older kernels (I do not know until when) needs `acl` as mount option. So you may try:

```
mount -o remount,acl /
```

**/etc/fstab**

Your `fstab` contains a line like

```
/dev/sda3   /  ext4    defaults    0 0
```

You have to add `acl` to the options field:

```
/dev/sda3   /  ext4    defaults,acl    0 0
```

Comment: I ran `remout` but still same result

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride Does `mount | grep -w /` now show `acl`? Can you add `acl` to the `fstab` entry and reboot?

Comment: It doesn't show `acl` I will update `fstab`.

Comment: Can you leave short note on updating `fstab` I haven't done that before.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride See the edit